# Highcharts - How to get Max and Min value between 2 dates

Tags: highcharts, max, intervals, min

I try to get the max and min value between two dates. Dates are on the yAxis and data on the xAxis.

But I don't know how to make an interval with 2 dates.

If someone have an idea.Thanks

Comment: You really need to provide some more information. Try posting some code of what you have tried already, or even better, post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes) function